# How to multiple chained filters are executed with Or between as default in ODATA?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, odata

I am using

> [devnixs/ODataAngularResources](https://github.com/devnixs/ODataAngularResources)

for integrating odata in my angular project. I am using angular 1.5 version. The default filter are executed as AND query for search.

```
 var User = $odataresource('/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'});
 var myUsers =   User.odata()
                    .filter("Name", "John")
                    .filter("Age",">",20)
                    .skip(10)
                    .take(20)
                    .orderBy("Name","desc")
                    .query();
```

As you can see there are two filter and as default they are executed as AND query for search. I need to use OR query for search.

Comment: have you looked into the documentation before posting?
because its right here: https://github.com/devnixs/ODataAngularResources#advanced-queries

Comment: for these we have to use predicate i just want to know if there is any other solution